# Why is the ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder) of the WebApplicationFactory class not being called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, integration-testing

I am writing an integration test, following its [MSdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

I am using a Custom `WebApplicationFactory<Program>`, where I need to override the `ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)` method to register some services and use a database of my choice, different from the one in prod.

The problem is this method is not being called. I'm doing exactly what that doc did, only that I'm not using XUnit. I use MSTest, which does not have the magical `IClassFixture` type.

I have tried the `ConfigureTestServices` and `ConfigureServices`

```cs
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
            builder.UseEnvironment(Environments.Development)
                .ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                var dbContextDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                    d => d.ServiceType ==
                        typeof(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>));
```

Why is the method not being called and how do I get it called?

*Edit* Adding my setup

The test itself, inheriting the `CustomWebApplicationFactory` class

```cs
 [TestClass]
 public class TransactionTest : CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>
 {
    private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;

    public TransactionTest(
            CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
    {
       this._factory = factory;
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Only_existing_users_can_transact()
    {

       var requestParam = new MyRequest
       {
         phone = "12345678",
       };
       ... some more code for acting and assertion
    }
}
```

The setup

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TProgram> : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram> where TProgram : class
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            { 
//Adding a breakpoint here does nothing. The breakpoint is never hit
                var dbContextDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                    d => d.ServiceType ==
                        typeof(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>));

                services.Remove(dbContextDescriptor);

                var dbConnectionDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                    d => d.ServiceType ==
                        typeof(DbConnection));

                services.Remove(dbConnectionDescriptor);

                
            });

            builder.UseEnvironment("Development");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you initialize an application in the tests? Please edit the code.

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek I don't understand what you mean by "initialize an application in the tests" but I have updated the code to include the test class and setup

Comment: The doc in question is using xUnit and the test class is implementing `IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>>`.

Comment: I know, and I said it in the question. Does this mean we cannot get this working with MSTests as  it does not have `IClassFixture`?

Comment: Try newing up the factory in the ctor instead of accepting it as a parameter

Comment: did that, did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use **MSTest** or **NUnit** you have to initialize `WebApplicationFactory`.

```
[TestClass]
public sealed class ExampleTests : IDisposable
{
    private CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> webApplicationFactory;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.webApplicationFactory.Dispose();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        this.webApplicationFactory.Dispose();
    }
    
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestMethodToTestSomething()
    {
        // Arrange
        this.webApplicationFactory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>();

        var httpClient = this.webApplicationFactory.CreateClient();

        // Act
        // ...

        // Assert
        // ...
    }
}
```

Side note:
Usually, when I need to change registered services, I don't customize `WebApplicationFactory` (as you) but [customize the client with `WithWebHostBuilder()`](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#customize-the-client-with-withwebhostbuilder).

Comment: this works. It hit the breakpoint. I believe I should be able to take it from here. Thank you.

Comment: @IsaacIkusika, glad to hear. Please upvote if a solution is OK for you.